# Three.js Use Skeleton like an Armature in Blender?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to create a skeleton in Three.js like an armature in Blender with an animation and append separate skinned meshes (with their own bones) to the skeleton and constrain those bones with the same name from the meshes to the skeleton's bones?

For example, you have a skeleton (armature) of a person and then append the person's body mesh and then maybe a sword mesh and other armor meshes. Doing it this way you wouldn't have to save the animations (the way that I'm currently doing it) into each individual mesh (reducing their file sizes) and instead save the animations only into the skeleton (armature). Reducing the mesh file sizes this way would be wonderful for reducing my site's bandwidth.

I saw that there is a Skeleton object already in the Three.js source, but it seems based on the given example to be used in conjunction with the SkeletonHelper to display the skeleton of an existing Mesh and not as a standalone entity.

So is it possible to use the Skeleton object or some other Three.js object to achieve the armature from Blender analogy?

Comment: wonder if you found an answer to the question..

Comment: @cesarpachon the discussion was continued on GitHub: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5212 ... there are some options, but not fully solved.